# How to exclude the #VALUE! or #DIV/0! in a column for calculating average using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, average

I have a situation to calculate the average value for a column (this column have many rows with numbers and some rows with `#DIV/0!` and `#VALUE!`).

I have a macro written for calculating average function. If its full of numbers, then it easily calculates the average of the column, but if has some `#VALUE!` or `#DIV/0!` in a cell. then it returns blank cell. How can I exclude the `#VALUE!` and `#DIV/0!` error and to take average for only numbers.

I have over 5K files to calculate the average.

```
Private Function data As Boolean
    Dim Avg_velocity  As String
    Dim Avg_length As String
    Avg_velocity  = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Sheets("Data").Range("K5:K650"))
    Avg_length  = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Sheets("Data").Range("I7:I607"))

    Sheets("Log").Range("A2:AI2").Insert
    Sheets("Log").Cells(2, "AA").value = Avg_velocity
    Sheets("Log").Cells(2, "AB").value = Avg_length
End Function
```

[image: average value affecting because of #VALUE!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just use AverageIf to ignore errors by providing a criteria of a really large number, like this:

```
Avg_velocity = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Sheets("Data").Range("K5:K650"), "<9E307")
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work quite ok:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRng1  As Range
    Dim myCell  As Range
    Dim myRng2  As Range

    Set myRng1 = Range("A1:A5")

    For Each myCell In myRng1
        If Not IsError(myCell) Then
            If Not myRng2 Is Nothing Then
                Set myRng2 = Union(myRng2, myCell)
            Else
                Set myRng2 = myCell
            End If
        End If
    Next myCell

    If Not myRng2 Is Nothing Then myRng2.Select

End Sub
```

It goes through the range and kindly picks up only the cells, which are not errors:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Should also be able to use aggregate function

```
=Application.worksheetFunction.Aggregate(1,6,range)
```

Comment: As long as you aren't lumbered with a version pre-2010. ;)

Comment: Can’t remember if subtotal has an existing option that may might compensate #google

Comment: No, it doesn't. That's one of the best things about AGGREGATE. :)